# Getting "Execution context was destroyed" when injecting scripts with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am trying to load a list of pages via Puppeteer and inject two scripts that fetch content from them.

The full error is:

```
Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of navigation.
```

I'm adding `page.addScriptTag()` to the `Promise.all()`. This seems to make the scraping fail.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  for (const url of links) {
    await retry(
      () =>
        Promise.all([
          page.goto(siteUrl + url),
          page.waitForNavigation(),
          page.waitForSelector('body'),
          page.addScriptTag({ path: 'util.js' }),
          page.addScriptTag({
            path: 'scrape.js',
            content: `const url = ${url}`,
          }),
        ])
          .then(() => {
            init(page, url, siteUrl);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err)),
      5
    );
  }
})();
```

The `init()` is just to run and evaluate, which is where I'd run functions that are in the injected scripts.

```
const init = async (page, url, siteUrl) => {
  return await page.evaluate(
    async (url, siteUrl) => {
      console.log('ev ', url, siteUrl);
      //Not doing anything here yet. 
    
    },
    url,
    siteUrl
  );
};
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think using `Promise.all` for consecutive tasks is not needed. Try just using consecutive `await`s.
2. You do not need `page.waitForNavigation()` with `page.goto()`, it is implied, both may hang the flow.
3. `page.waitForSelector('body')` also seems excessive as `page.goto()` waits for `'load'` event that implies presense of body.
4. If you need `addScriptTag()` in each page, consider using [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args), but I am not sure here.
5. I doubt that `page.addScriptTag()` can use both `path` and `content` options.